# get the text in a list item and modify it with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, listitem

I have a bunch of HTML list items and what i want is to be able to read the text of a list item and then be able to give the user the ability to modify it. the structure of each list item is the same:

```
<li id='1' class='attachment'>
    <a href='link.html'>TEXT VALUE I WANT TO READ AND MODIFY</a>
    <a href='link2.html'><img src'img1.jpg'></a>
    <a href='link3.html'><img src'img2.jpg'></a>
</li>
```

at the moment i am able to get the list item using

```
li = document.getElementById(id);
```

but if i get it to print out something like

```
li.childNodes[?] 
li.childNodes[?].data
li.childNodes[?].nodeValue etc...
```

i am never able to get it to print "TEXT VALUE I WANT TO READ AND MODIFY", it always gives null, undefined or [object Text] or something similar. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the *textContent* or *innerText* properties:

```
var li = document.getElementById(id);
var t = "textContent" in li.childNodes[0] ? "textContent" : "innerText";
alert(li.childNodes[0][t]);
```

*innerText* is implemented by IE and *textContent* is implemented by standards compliant browsers.

Alternatively, if you're certain that the element's first child will be a text node, you can use

```
alert(li.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

---

Based on your comment below, we can make a safe assumption that white-space is interfering with the *childNodes* property in your example.  This is normal - *childNodes* returns both elements and text nodes that are direct descendants of the given element.  The alternative is to use *children* in newer browsers:

```
// 1st example using `children` instead
var li = document.getElementById(id);
var t = "textContent" in li ? "textContent" : "innerText";
alert(li.children[0][t]);

// 2nd example using `children` instead
alert(li.children[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

*children* isn't supported pre Firefox 3.5 and in other older browsers.  You could use *li.getElementsByTagName("a")* for the example that you've posted - but bear in mind that it will return all *<a>* element descendants, not just immediate children.

Comment: i like either of your suggestions but for some reason it still does not work. if i create a loop and print out all childnodes i get 0=>[object Text] 1=>link.html 2=>[object Text] 3=>link2.html 4=>[object Text] 5=>link3.html 6=>[object Text]. i think the text i am looking for is in 2, however if i then print out everything in 2 i get 20 elements each being undefined. any ideas?

Comment: @Mitch: ah, you've run into the famous "white-space = TextNode" issue with *childNodes*.  I've updated my answer with a solution.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
var li = document.getElementById(1);
var a = li.getElementsByTagName('a');

alert(a[0].innerHTML);
```

And before anyone can suggest to just use jQuery, here's the equivalent:

```
$('li#someid a').html();
```

In my opinion, if you're doing fine without jQuery, don't use it.

Comment: You shouldn't use *innerHTML* or *html()* to get the text value of an element.  Both will return html encoded characters such as `&nbsp;`, `&gt;`, `&lt;`, etc.

Comment: @Andy E, that is true, it's just a bad habit I have as I have never run into any problems when using innerHTML/html().