# How do I properly handle any change actions to my dropdown-menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down menu and I want to trigger something when click on them.
I'm not sure if I should use `.change` or `.click` or which one is the best practice foe something like this.

But right now I use `.click`.

[image]

---

## HTML

```
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1"> <span class="summary-texts">Summary</span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
       <!-- Dynamic List will added here  -->
   </ul>
</div>
```

---

## What I used to have

```
$('#group-0').click(function() {
  updateInfo("0");
  chart.draw( data[0] , options);
  $("#dd.wrapper-dropdown-1 .summary-texts").text('Group 0 ');
});
$('#group-1').click(function() {
  updateInfo("1");
  chart.draw( data[1] , options);
  $("#dd.wrapper-dropdown-1 .summary-texts").text('Group 1 ');
});
$('#group-2').click(function() {
  updateInfo("2");
  chart.draw( data[2] , options);
  $("#dd.wrapper-dropdown-1 .summary-texts").text('Group 2 ');
});
$('#group-3').click(function() {
  updateInfo("3");
  chart.draw( data[3] , options);
  $("#dd.wrapper-dropdown-1 .summary-texts").text('Group 3 ');
});
$('#group-4').click(function() {
  updateInfo("4");
  chart.draw( data[4] , options);
  $("#dd.wrapper-dropdown-1 .summary-texts").text('Group 4 ');
});
```

It's not so good as you can see, a lot of hard code values. so I refactor my code.

---

## What I have now

```
for (var assignment in objects.assignments ) {

$('#group-'+assignment).click(function() {
  updateInfo(assignment);
  chart.draw( data[assignment] , options);
  $("#dd.wrapper-dropdown-1 .summary-texts").text('Group '+assignment);
});

}
```

---

## Result

When I select anything from the drop-down menu, It keep displaying `Group 4`.
I'm not sure why it does that.

Am I optimize it the right way ?

How do I handle any change actions of my dropdown-menu ?

Any helps / hints / suggestions will be a huge help for me.

Comment: what library are you using for the select?

Comment: Not really a library, I just style it with css.

Comment: Instead of a for loop I'd something like `$('[id^="group-"']).on('click',function(){var assignment=$(this).attr('id').replace('group-','');/*assignment code*/});`

Comment: @depperm : feel free to answer, so it easier to read that way. Just saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider what your code is currently doing:

> Iterate over `objects.assignments`, defining `assignment` as a
>   variable within the current *execution context*. On each iteration,
>   take the next enumerable property of `object.assignments` and give it
>   to `assignments`.

If for example after the `for` loop were completed you added `console.log(assignment)` you will find that it writes *the last value given to `assignment` in the `for` loop*: 4. Why? Because the variable `assignment` is not confined to the `for` loop. `For` loops **do not create their own scope**.

Therefore, when any of the click handlers are invoked, they will be accessing the last value given to `assignment`, which is 4.

We can avoid this issue by using jQuery's `each()` function, as **functions do create their own scope**.

```
$.each(objects.assignments, function(index, value) {
    $('#group-' + index).click(function() {
        updateInfo(index);
        chart.draw(data[index] , options);
        $("#dd.wrapper-dropdown-1 .summary-texts").text('Group ' + index);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank-you for your concise answer. :)

Comment: I like your answer the most among all of them, but I'm not sure why it is not working. It give me this error in the console `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #group-[object Object]`

Comment: My mistake: try using `index` in place of `value` within the function.For example, `$('#group-' + value).click(function() {` becomes `$('#group-' + index).click(function() {`. If this works, I will amend my answer.

Comment: You're right. It fixed. It works 100%. Well done. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I would get rid of the for loop and just use jquery. The `^=` in the selector listens to ids that start with `group-`. To get the actual group number you need to remove `group-` otherwise assignment will be something like `group-2` instead of just `2`.

```
$('#dropdown li').on('click',function(){
  var assignment=$(this).attr('id').replace('group-','');
  updateInfo(assignment);
  chart.draw( data[assignment] , options);
  $("#dd.wrapper-dropdown-1 .summary-texts").text('Group '+assignment);
});
```

Comment: Thank-you for doing as my request. :)

Comment: Wow. this is a really cool solution. If you can add a very short explanation to it, this will be perfect. for example - `^=` ? Also, why do we need to use **replace** ? just curious. :)

Comment: if data uses ints for keys you may need to add `parseInt` around assignment

Comment: Good tip, I will note that one.

Comment: Your first line has an error `$('[id^="group-"']).on('click',function(){`  - just letting you know.

Comment: I believe I fixed it, single quote needed to be moved over one

Comment: You are adding a listener on each `li`. This produces bad performance because multiple listener and complete DOM parsing. And if anything in the page also has an id starting with group-, il will get the listener. You don't want that :)

Comment: Better with the edit, but still not good. What you wanted to write is that : `$('#dropdown [id^="group-"]')` : you forgot the pound. But still not good. `$('#dropdown').find('[id^="group-"]')` will perform better. Because what you wrote will make jQuery to parse the entire DOM bottom up, find all the nodes with an id starting with goup- and then check if the parent is #dropdown. ( this is why people should know better the internals of jquery :) )

Comment: And the best way from far is to delegate the listener to the parent, like that : `$("#dropdown").on( "click", "li", function( e ) {...` One listener instead of multiple, parsing top down instead of bottom up because id and stop when the first element with the corresponding id is found.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a new click event for each item (what happens when an item doesn't match your pattern "group-x"?) add a click event on the "ul" element, or if you have to, on each "li" element and get the text by using the "innerText" or "textProperty" property of the DOM element.

Here are some examples:

[get the text in a list item and modify it with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804009/get-the-text-in-a-list-item-and-modify-it-with-javascript)

[How to get Value / Text of a List item Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185963/how-to-get-value-text-of-a-list-item-javascript)

I would personally try to set the click event as high as possible to keep the code clean on the page and the load time lower.

Comment: Thank you for keeping helping me on last post and this one.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options :

1° : use a select :

```
<select>
    <option value='v'>text</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Then you will add a change listener on the select.

2° : do it the way you are doing it (and it may be a good option for styling questions), but tweak it a little bit. First, append your options properly, like that :

```
[ {
  "text": "Group 0",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "text": "Group 1",
  "value": 2
}, {
  "text": "Group 2",
  "value": 3
}, {
  "text": "Group 3",
  "value": 4
} ].forEach( function( el ) {
  $( "#dropdown" ).append( "<li data-info=\" + el.value + "\">" + el.text + "</li>" )
} );
```

Then, you should use event delegation. Add the click event on the ul. This is really better performance wise and it will allow you to append options after the event attachement.

```
$("#dropdown").on( "click", "li", function( e ) {
  console.log( $( e.target ).data( "info" ) )
  updateInfo( $( e.target ).data( "info" ) );
  chart.draw( data[ $( e.target ).data( "info" ) ] , options);
} );
```

I've made you a js bin to play with it : https://jsbin.com/posuzeyija/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a 'select' element be better than having an 'ul' and using CSS to make it work as a dropdown?

Anyway, '.change' and '.click' are different things. The first will act when an item has been changed, so if you click the same item as you had selected before, nothing will execute. The latter will run the code every time you click *any* of the elements, regardless of what was previously selected. You need to consider which one you want or need.

Here's a quick solution to create it with a select: http://jsfiddle.net/sf3buwbq/

```
$('#select').change(function() {
   $(this).find("option:selected");
});
```

I'm not sure if you understand that this can be achieved, and that you can store all the information you would want in the

```
<option> </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me modify your code. The html can look like the following.

```
<ul class="dropdown">
       <li class="groups" id="group-1">
       <li class="groups" id="group-2">
   </ul>
```

And just get rid of the assignment loop

```
$('.groups').click(function() {
var element_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
  updateInfo(element_id);
  chart.draw( data[element_id] , options);
  $("#dd.wrapper-dropdown-1 .summary-texts").text('Group '+element_id);
});
```

Enjoy!!